# Creating a document for taking notes about a book using Git?

Tags: ms-word, document

I have never used Git before.  I am supposed to use it to take notes on a book, but i haven't a clue how to get started. Do I create a .text file? The only things I have found are instructions on how to keep track of projects, but nothing about the kinds of projects I might use. I just want to make a word document that can be read, altered, and printed with ease. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you sure you were directed to use git? Git is purely a version control system. You could create a directory of files (text, images etc) and manage their history with git, but that's about it...

Comment: I am supposed to takes notes and track the history of the document using Git. How would I do this? And what kind of document format should I use?

Answer (score 2):

To take advantage in using git for storing documentation you should use non binary formats like:

- html
- latex
- pure text
- markdown

There are many text formats that can be used for this.

Comment: You could use the Flat OPC XML format, which is the single xml text file version of a docx.