# Tracking document history using Git?

Tags: document, history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a document for taking notes about a book using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177729/creating-a-document-for-taking-notes-about-a-book-using-git)

I have never used Git before. I am supposed to takes notes on a book in a document file and track the history of the document using Git. How would I do this? And what kind of document format should I use?

Comment: duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177729/creating-a-document-for-taking-notes-about-a-book-using-git

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the document format, you have to keep in mind that one great feature of version control is that it can answer "what did I change between day X and day Y" by generating a so-called diff of your document. This pretty much only works if your document is in a plaintext sort of format, for example txt, html, tex, but not in a binary format such as doc, docx, odx. (Oh, it wil display changes alright, but it'll look like nothing you can ever understand as a human.)

If you need formatting, I'd probably recommend plain simple HTML or something like RST or markdown (which are easy formatting languages like the one used here) unless you already know LaTeX.